# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2012 Express instance outside a VM

Tags: sql-server, hyper-v, windows

I'm trying to connect to a SqlServer instance - located in my host machine - from my VM, using Sql Server Management Studio.

From my host I can connect to both SQL instances using SSMS, but when I try to connect to the host instance from the VM, SMSS gives this error message (mine is in PT-BR):

[image]

My environment is like this: the blue dotted block represents my host (PC_MASTER) and the orange dotted block represents my VM (MYVM):

[image]

Here are the main components in each machine:

**PC-MASTER (Host):** Windows 8 PRO-English w/ SQL Server 2012 Express. SQL instance name is "***PC-MASTER\SQLEXPRESS***".

**MyVM (VM):** Windows Server 2012 BR-Portuguese w/ SQL Server 2012 Standard. SQL instance name is "***MYVM***".

**Firewall:** The host has an inbound rule opening the 1433/1434 TCP ports for all programs/services;

**SQL Protocols:** In both servers all 3 main protocols are on, in the following order: Shared Memory, TCP/IP and Named Pipes;

**Remote Access:** Both SQL servers are configured to allow remote connections;

SQL Configuration: The host SQL is configured to allow only static access through the port 1433, as Somantra pointed out.

**From my VM(MYVM):**

- I can only connect to the local SQL instance.
- I can ping the host successfully using either its IP or its name;
- I cannot connect to the host using telnet: I tried the ports 21, 23, 80, 1433 and 1434.

Tks!

Comment: Did you configure a listening port for PC-MASTER\SQLEXPRESS in SQL Server Configuration Manager? http://screencast.com/t/EX2COv1mF2iJ

Comment: Hi Somantra, tks for the tip! Unfortunatelly it does not solved the problem, the error message is still appearing in the VM.

Comment: Hi Tom Tom/Tom O'Connor: 

Can you give me a more direct guidance about how rephrase this question? I believe it's in the right forum, since I saw a lot of similar questions here, and I listed all info/configs I know. If I knew ALL things beforehand, I probably would have solved it already...

I understand the main goal of this forums is to help people with their problems - no matter how silly it must appears to others - and holding a question with little/none explanations on how to rephrase it correctly goes against this goal, right?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Named instances use a different set of ports, not just :1433. You need at least :1434 and the port of your instance. See the answer on: http://serverfault.com/questions/130549/ms-sql-server-firewall-ports

Answer (score 5):

So I spent a few minutes looking at all the duplicates of this problem, and [there are a few](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=site:serverfault.com%20sql%20server%20named%20instance%201434&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=6FF5U6mJGu_RmAX4tIHwCA#channel=sb&q=site:serverfault.com%20sql%20server%20named%20instance%201434&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official), but to be honest they all kind of sucked in terms of their answers, so here we go:

Port 1433 is only good for default instances of SQL Server. If you are going to connect to a named instance, you have two options:

1. Use `SERVER\INSTANCE` name and open ports 1434 (for SQL Browser) and the port of your SQL Server Instance (more on that later)
2. Use `SERVER:port` where `port` is the port of your SQL Server Instance

To determine which port your SQL Server instance is running on in the SQL Server Configuration Manager, under Network Configuration > TCP/IP > IP Addresses:

[image]

So for #1 I need to open 1434 and 64670 and for #2 I just need to open 64670, but use a different SQL connection string.

Comment: Tks a lot Mark, I'll test it today ASAP!